# Typescript - Type definition of object literal

Tags: typescript

I have an object like so - an int followed by a string, I tried setting the type like below, however it doesn't seem valid. I guess it's something really simple I'm missing.

```
const months: { int: string; } = { 
        0: 'JAN',
        1: 'FEB',
        2: 'MAR'
}
```

Update: I just found this works - correct?

```
const months: { [number: number]: string } = { ... }
```

or is my only generic option to use:

```
const months: any = { 
        0: 'JAN',
        1: 'FEB',
        2: 'MAR'
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to annotate the type at all? If you just write `const months = {0: 'JAN', 1: 'FEB', 2: 'MAR'};`, the compiler will infer its type as `{0: string, 1: string, 2: string}`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMVn6W).  Is that not acceptable to you?  If not, why not?  You can write `Record<number, string>` but this will accept values like `{"-1.23e+45": "hey"}`. Is that what you want?  The use cases are important since they will determine how wide or narrow of a type you want.  You might want something [very specific](https://tsplay.dev/w6X7ym) for all I know.

Comment: @jcalz - I tried without annotation, but I get the error: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ 0: string; 1: string; 2: string; }'.ts(7053)` if I call: `months[now.getMonth()]`

Comment: Well, `getMonth()` returns `number` instead something like `0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11`.  If all you're going to do with `months` is read `months[now.getMonth()]` then `Record<string, number>` is reasonable (as long as you don't enable `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess`).  But if you read `months[98765]` the compiler will assume it's `string` even though it will be `undefined`.  If `months[now.getMonth()]` the primary use case?  Do you need to protect against unexpected numeric indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're essentially saying is month is of type `{int: string}` where the created objects must have *int* property of type *string*. As in,

```
{
  int: '1' 
}
```

What you really want is a dictionary type and you'd create one like this.

```
const months: { [int: number]: string } = 
  { 
    0: 'JAN'
  }
```

Checkout [this](https://www.carlrippon.com/typescript-dictionary/) for further information.

Comment: Thanks for that link - I see that doc also shows `Record<number, string>` - looks cleaner to read! Any things I needs to be aware of with that approach?

Comment: @userMod2 Unfortunately, I'm unfamiliar with Record to give you a good answer. There are quite a few utility types offered by Typescript for ease of use, I suppose.